# Declare local storage for more than 4 bytes x86 assembly MASM

Tags: assembly, x86, local, masm

There does not seem to be a way to declare 1 variable that can get more than 4 bytes allocated to the stack in x86 Assembly MASM, I locate my store like this

```
;METHOD 1
method1 PROC stdcall uses eax ebx, val1:dword
     LOCAL tempString, dTemp
```

I've tryed allocating bytes like this:

```
;METHOD 1
method1 PROC stdcall uses eax ebx, val1:dword
     LOCAL tempString byte 12 dup(?)
     LOCAL dTemp
```

but it causes error message `A2008: syntax error : byte`
How can I allocate storage for one variable that's got more than 4 bytes allocated to the stack?

Like.. I don't understand why I cant simply allocate a string of bytes?

Answer (score 3):

You can simply allocate multiple bytes using this syntax:

`strTemp[12]:byte`

The above statement would allocate 12 bytes to the stack identified by the identifier **strtemp**.